# Aligning a formtable with button

Tags: html, css

In the below code how to align the the print button next to the table and not below or above it.

```
<div id="content">
    <form action="Empform" method="post" name="emp">
            <table>
            <tr><th>Name</t></tr>
            <tr><td></td></tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Comments: </label>
        <br>
        <textarea rows=10 cols=75></textarea>
    </form>
    <input type="button" value="Copy" id="print" onclick="javascript:copy();" style="display:inline;/>
    <br>
</div>
```

Thanks..

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do … but your HTML is badly invalid and will trigger very different error recovery approaches in browsers. `<tr>` elements can only be children of `<tbody>`, `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` elements (and `<table>` elements in XHTML) — **not** `<form>` elements.

Comment: Removed the jQuery code as it was irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Sorry i had missed the table tags while posting..

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the form.